# Making a script run in the background

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a python script and it should run all the time on my computer but I want it to be hidden. How can I hide the console so that the user doesn't have to see it in his taskbar the entire time?

Comment: Just run the script, and it will run forever...

Comment: ... and maybe add it to your autostart folder or cron, depending on your os

Comment: It will run forever taking 100% of the cpu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment as < 50 rep :/

Save the python file as .pyw (This removes the console)

File will run without the console 'hiding' it

Close it by using Taskkill or task manager

**EDIT**
If you want the program to launch on start up, put a shortcut or the file in the startup file

To get there go to run ***(Window + R)***
 and type **shell:startup**

Copy your file into the directory

Answer (score -1):

If you're on windows or any os you can try  this

from editor jump to **file >> save as >> yourname.pyw** ... then you can run the saved file

> **what this will do ??** 
>   it will basically hide the little noisy terminal/cmd windows ..that's it :)

it will be better if you tells us what op your're on .