# Can PyAutoGui be runned in background of my pc

Tags: python, pyautogui

I was making some, let's say, a program Spammer. In that case, I used a module called `PyAutoGUI` which allows *Python* to move the mouse or typewrite words or even press buttons on a keyboard.

To activate my program, I need to be in any window and then press my program. For example, I am in *Facebook* and then I've pressed my program. It needs to write: **I can't be on Facebook**.

So, How could my program work in the background on the window that my game is in?

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
def spams(xywords):
  x_cor = 962
  y_cor=541
  print(xywords)
  if upali:
    print("Test test")
    pyautogui.click(962,541)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    pyautogui.typewrite(xywords)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    pyautogui.typewrite('random stuff')
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(4)

spams("HELLO")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40706161/4180176

Comment: You missunderstood. I know that if I do that i wont see a python but when i open a facebook it will start spamming what i typed i facebook, i want it o spam on PARTICURAL WINDOW

Comment: Very hard to understand what you want. Maybe could you provide some diagram how it should be working?

Comment: That's great idea @Uginius Malukas. So I just love to automate games and make some cool programs. In my game when you press "enter" You type what you want to say and then press "enter" to send it. I want to make it just a bit better , How? Well here is how, I can window down my game and be in facebook or where ever I want But it should still be spamming it my game,

Comment: @Duke Smith. So you want to run this script which uses the cursor to make clicks etc on a minimised game? This would not work. What you are most likely trying to make is a API for the game. What you are doing right now won't work the way you want it to.

Comment: So how could i make it then? Is there a way ? I was people do this...